# partially shade the histogram in python

Tags: python, histogram

I have a distribution histogram, because I will use this distribution to do some cuts. I would like to shade the region for my cuts. I know how to shade it all, but I do not know how to shade some part of the histogram. Below is my code:

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=False, sharey=True,figsize=(20,8))
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator3)
ax1.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator4)
ax1.tick_params('both', length=10, width=2, which='major')
ax1.tick_params('both', length=5, width=2, which='minor')
ax1.set_xlabel(r'$\log\mathcal{L} ~[\odot]$',fontsize=30)
ax1.set_ylabel(r'Number of galaxies',fontsize=30)
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.set_xlim(6,13.5)
bins = np.linspace(6,13,141)
ax1.hist(L,bins,histtype='step')

ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator5)
ax2.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator6)
ax2.tick_params('both', length=10, width=2, which='major')
ax2.tick_params('both', length=5, width=2, which='minor')
ax2.set_xlabel(r'$r_e ~{\rm [Kpc]}$',fontsize=30)
ax2.set_yscale('log')
bins = np.linspace(0,25,251)
ax2.hist(R50,bins,histtype='step')
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.005, left=0.15, right=0.9, top=0.95, bottom=0.05)
plt.savefig('R50_hist.eps',bbox_inches='tight')
```

And the plot is below:

I want to shade the left panel from x=10 to x=11 (right panel from x=2 to x=10) and below the histogram, anyone can offer me some idea how to approach it?

[image]

Comment: "below the histogram above y=0"; I'm not sure what you mean by that, since everything is above 0. I assume its just extra, since shading between x=10 and x=11 implies all of the y-values (which is also implied by the fact that it's a histogram: there's not much use in shading something above, say, y > 100).

Comment: Yes, your are right. I will just revise it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward: you just overplot a bar histogram, with the appropriate colour, and ensure the linewidth (`lw`) is zero.

For example (I don't have your dataset, obviously):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

N = 1e5
lum = 10**10.5 * np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=1, size=1e5)
lum = np.log10(lum)
dist = np.random.normal(loc=5, scale=5, size=1e5)

f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=False, sharey=True,figsize=(20,8))
# Not bothered with the locators
#ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator3)
#ax1.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator4)
ax1.tick_params('both', length=10, width=2, which='major')
ax1.tick_params('both', length=5, width=2, which='minor')
ax1.set_xlabel(r'$\log\mathcal{L} ~[\odot]$',fontsize=30)
ax1.set_ylabel(r'Number of galaxies',fontsize=30)
ax1.set_yscale('log')
ax1.set_xlim(6,13.5)
bins = np.linspace(6,13,141)
ax1.hist(lum,bins,histtype='step')
# Subselect the luminosities
mask = (lum >= 10) & (lum <= 11)
# Overplot colored bar histogram
ax1.hist(lum[mask],bins,histtype='bar', color='red', lw=0)

#ax2.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator5)
#ax2.yaxis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator6)
ax2.tick_params('both', length=10, width=2, which='major')
ax2.tick_params('both', length=5, width=2, which='minor')
ax2.set_xlabel(r'$r_e ~{\rm [Kpc]}$',fontsize=30)
ax2.set_yscale('log')
bins = np.linspace(0,25,251)
ax2.hist(dist,bins,histtype='step')

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.005, left=0.15, right=0.9, top=0.95, bottom=0.05)
plt.savefig('R50_hist.png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

It's left as an exercise to the reader to do something similar for the right part of the figure.